# How to List only the users created by a particular user

Tags: user-access, users

How can I list only the users created by any particular logged in user.

Suppose,I'm a Subscriber and there are users already registered, I then added User1(as Associate), User2(as Subscriber). When I list the users, I shall be only able to view the users that are added by me (i.e., User1 and User2). No other user details shall be visible to me

Comment: I could swear that I saw this being answered just the other day here. Please perform a quick search and see if you find anything. Or someone else may know which entry I refer to... EDIT: No, slightly different: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/188863/how-to-allow-an-user-role-to-create-a-new-user-under-a-role-which-lower-than-his

Comment: Thank you., But I need a plugin, if there is any.
And I found nothing regarding the user creator. Hierarchy is not the issue here., I can add a user of any role., but I need to view list of only the user, created by me

Comment: Please be aware that plugin recommendations are off-topic on [wordpress.se].

Comment: If the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)?« and/or »[Why is voting important](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?«, more information about the [wordpress.se] model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 0):

WordPress does not save the information about, who created whom. If so, then the most plausible place would be the [`wp_users` table](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_users), but as you can see, it is not happening. As you did not find a plugin offering this functionality, you have to create and implement the functionality yourself. How to approach that is on another sheet though.

Comment: Can you share the link to approach this., Please

Comment: Sorry, but I do not have a single link to a solution for you. @user3664956