# Allow role to edit users at lower level with only specific metadata

Tags: user-meta, user-roles

How to allow a custom role, `company-administrator`, to be able to edit/create/delete users lower than their level, `subscriber`, where some metadata is matched?

To elaborate: I'm making a membership site and would like to have a user role which can administer users for their company/organisation only. So, I was thinking to create an email domain whitelist metadata at the `company-administrator` level editable only by `administrators`, enabling them to only manage `subscribers` whose email address domain matches the whitelist (unless there's a more sensible way to achieve this).

[How to allow an user role to create a new user under a role which lower than his level only?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/188863/how-to-allow-an-user-role-to-create-a-new-user-under-a-role-which-lower-than-his) has got me part of the way, just need to integrate the metadata whitelist.